# Using SNMP++ method with callback in .mm file

Tags: ios, function-pointers, objective-c-blocks, snmp, objective-c++

I am using SNMP++ library in my project and everything works fine. However, there is a method where I need to get callback in my .mm file. Now when I am creating a block and passing it to that function as parameter, it throws an error "No matching member function for call to 'get_bulk'". Here is the piece of code:

```
    void(^callbackFunc)(int,Snmp*,Pdu&,SnmpTarget&,void*);
callbackFunc = ^(int i,Snmp* s,Pdu& p,SnmpTarget& t,void* v) {

};
snmp.get_bulk(pdu, *target, l_repeaters, l_repetitions,callbackFunc);
```

Also, here is the function signature for "get_bulk" function:

```
int Snmp::get_bulk(Pdu &pdu,                 // pdu to use
               const SnmpTarget &target, // destination target
               const int non_repeaters,  // number of non repeaters
               const int max_reps,       // maximum number of repetitions
               const snmp_callback callback,// callback to use
               const void * callback_data)  // callback data
{
  pdu.set_type( sNMP_PDU_GETBULK_ASYNC);
  return snmp_engine( pdu, non_repeaters, max_reps, target,
                  callback, callback_data);
}
```

What should I pass in 'callback' type?
This is the typedef for SNMP_callback:

```
typedef void (*snmp_callback)(int reason, Snmp *session,
                           Pdu &pdu, SnmpTarget &target, void *data);
```

I am stuck on this for the past 4-5 hours now and I can't figure out how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's blocks are not convertible to function pointers, as they also contain data (captured variables, etc.) and a reference counting mechanism. You will need to pass a free function, static C++ class member function, or a C++ non-capturing lambda as the callback.

The lambda is the closest syntactically to a block; only non-capturing lambdas are convertible to a function pointer, however, so you will need to do the capturing "by hand" by passing a pointer to a context struct or similar through the `void* callback_data` argument which presumably is passed through to the callback as `void* data`.

The lambda will look something like this:

```
snmp_callback callback =
    [](int reason, Snmp *session, Pdu &pdu, SnmpTarget &target, void *data)
    {
        // context_struct_type* context = static_cast<context_struct_type*>(data);
    };
```